# Can we replace UPPER function by making upper in java?

Tags: java, hibernate

I want remove upper function used in hql and make in upper at java side. following is the query:-

```
String hql = "SELECT addType FROM addrDO WHERE **UPPER**(id.address) = **UPPER**('"+ address +"')";
```

I want use `toUpperCase()` java funtion instead of using UPPER in query, like `"id.address".toUpperCase()` and `address.toUpperCase()` at java side and now query should be like

```
String hql = "SELECT addType FROM addrDO WHERE id.address = address;
```

Will above work any side effect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first query uses the `UPPER` function to implement a case insensitive comparison in the `WHERE` clause, the second uses case sensitive comparison.

Because the comparison has to be done in the database, you cannot replace it with Java's `toUpperCase` in the application layer.

Comment: all Addresses stored in my DB are in uppercase, hence want remove UPPER() from query that's why I am converting address in uppercase @ java side.

Comment: In that case there should be no problem, simply remove the `UPPER` from the query and use the `toUpperCase()` on the parameter. 
Another suggestion: In your query better use paramaters instead of concatenating the HQL text, otherwise you might suffer an SQL injection attack, if the variable `address` looks something like `123' or 1=1`

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to generate a dynamic query, which would finally be executed by a database server and not in JVM, thus you need to abide by the grammar of database server.

If you want to use java's toUpperCase method, better break your query and have something like

```
String idAddress = "id.address";
String address = "'\"+ address +\"'";

String hql = "SELECT addType FROM addrDO WHERE "+ idAddress.toUpperCase() +" = " + address.toUpperCase() + ";";
```

which is not suggestible, as you are unnecessarily using up jvm's memory